# refused mount request from 192.168.56.100 for /ovm/mypool1/poolfs (/): not exported

Tags: linux, nfs

Am trying to setup NFS mount point between servers:- 
db-rac and vm-manager. /ovm/mypool1/poolfs is a virtual disk mounted as shown below.

/dev/sdc               12G  159M   12G   2% /ovm/mypool1/poolfs

Following are my configurations:-

vm-manager(192.168.56.100):-

1) cat /etc/exports

/ovm/mypool1/poofs  *(rw,no_root_squash)

2) [root@mymanager ~]# chkconfig nfs on

[root@mymanager ~]# service nfs start

[root@mymanager ~]# exportfs –a

3) [root@vm-manager ~]# df -h

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                       19G  2.9G   15G  17% /
/dev/sda1              99M   17M   78M  18% /boot
tmpfs                 2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb1             9.9G  4.0G  5.5G  42% /u01
Downloads             233G   85G  149G  37% /media/sf_Downloads
/dev/sdc               12G  159M   12G   2% /ovm/mypool1/poolfs

4) [root@vm-manager ~]# rpcinfo -p 192.168.56.100
   program vers proto   port

```
100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
100011    1   udp    835  rquotad
100011    2   udp    835  rquotad
100011    1   tcp    838  rquotad
100011    2   tcp    838  rquotad
100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
100227    2   udp   2049  nfs_acl
100227    3   udp   2049  nfs_acl
100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
100227    2   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
100227    3   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
100021    1   udp  43381  nlockmgr
100021    3   udp  43381  nlockmgr
100021    4   udp  43381  nlockmgr
100021    1   tcp  39233  nlockmgr
100021    3   tcp  39233  nlockmgr
100021    4   tcp  39233  nlockmgr
100005    1   udp    867  mountd
100005    1   tcp    870  mountd
100005    2   udp    867  mountd
100005    2   tcp    870  mountd
100005    3   udp    867  mountd
100005    3   tcp    870  mountd
```

5) [root@vm-manager ~]# showmount -e

Export list for vm-manager.oracle.com:
/ovm/mypool1/poofs *

db-rac(192.168.56.101):-

While running the command 
[root@db-rac ~]#mount 192.168.56.100:/ovm/mypool1/poolfs /mnt -v

Am getting the error

mount: no type was given - I'll assume nfs because of the colon
mount: trying 192.168.56.100 prog 100003 vers 3 prot tcp port 2049
mount: trying 192.168.56.100 prog 100005 vers 3 prot udp port 867
mount: 192.168.56.100:/ovm/mypool1/poolfs failed, reason given by server: Permission denied

And checking the /var/log/messages

vm-manager mountd[2811]: refused mount request from 192.168.56.100 for /ovm/mypool1/poolfs (/): not exported

Appreciate for any help provided.

Comment: at 5) , is it poolfs or poofs ? and is there a space after ':' ?

Comment: I'm with @Ixer.  Your export list says "/ovm/mypool1/poofs" without a lowercase "L".

Comment: Yes it was the 'l' missing from pools...thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

Check the `/var/log/messages` and cross verify the spellings for the both, what you have exported and on what you are trying to mount. Most of the time it is because of typo.

Comment: ...and a particular mountpoint as well (was my case right now: the wrong _long_ line got modified).

Answer (score 2):

Reload nfs after changes in /etc/export

`service nfs restart` or `exportfs -r`

Comment: Done already but no luck. Can somebody explain me the meaning for '(/): not exported' also what does 2811 signify.

Comment: it means it is looking for '/' instead of the folder you have in your export file (and can not export it).  You probably have a typo somewhere.